# Can't get return from Azure authentication using magium active directory

Tags: php, laravel, azure-active-directory

I'm authenticating on an Azure application using a PHP script and function from a library called [magium/active directory](https://github.com/magium/active-directory). The login process happens flawlessly when I call the "authenticate" method. This method is supposed to return an "entity" object containing information about the user which is logged in (e.g: name).

```
public function doLogin() {
     session_start();
     $request = \Zend\Psr7Bridge\Psr7ServerRequest::fromZend(new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request())
     $ad = new \Magium\ActiveDirectory\ActiveDirectory(
            new \Magium\Configuration\Config\Repository\ArrayConfigurationRepository($this->config),
            $request)
        );
     $entity = $ad->authenticate();
}
```

However, if I try to get this entity object after the authentication line and "echo" it, nothing happens. If I try to write it to a database, nothing happens as well. If I try to store the value in session, it does not stay there (maybe the session is being refreshed by the lib?).

```
$entity = $ad->authenticate();
dd($entity); //this line does not seem to be called
```

It seems like the execution is being stopped and anything below the "authenticate" method call is being ignored. Has anyone ever experienced something like this?

Comment: Did you end up using this (now outdated) library for the solution, or did you have to migrate to something else?

Comment: Yes, I ended up using it (even though I do not intend to use it again in the future).

Answer (score 1):

After some time I understood the problem: after executing, the authenticate function calls "die()" and therefore anything that comes after it does not execute. You need to use a callback route to follow up with execution after auth. There is an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tutorial-step=3).

Comment: Awesome link - either it's me or their documentation is so overwhelming it's hard to find stuff.